# jQuery - <tr> delegate, ignore header row

Tags: jquery

I have a delegate created that responds to a row click in an HTML table. However, I would like this delegate to not fire if the user clicks the table header row. Can I modify the delegate definition easily to do this?

```
$("#listingTable").delegate('tr', 'click', function () {
var latitude = $(this).children('td').eq(3).text().trim();
var longitude = $(this).children('td').eq(4).text().trim();
```

Comment: wrap the body in <tbody></tbody> and catch only tbody tr clicks ?

Comment: Can we see your markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a class to the tr you dont want:

```
<tr class="ignore"><td>Nope</td></tr>
<tr><td>Yes</td></tr>

$("#listingTable").delegate('tr:not(.ignore)', 'click', function () { /* ... */})
```

---

Or use a table body:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr><th>exampleheader</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>Only this</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

$("#listingTable").delegate('tbody>tr', 'click', function () { /* ... */})
```

---

Or go all html5 on it:

```
<tr data-lat="123" data-lng="456"><td>Some td's value</td></tr>

$("#listingTable").delegate('tr', 'click', function () {
    if( typeof $(this).attr('data-lat') !=="undefined" ){

     }
})
```

Comment: Perfect. The tbody > tr is exactly what I'm looking for. Your first solution would cause me other problems because of code not shown here.

Comment: Great (y) I'm gonna leave the other two in case someone else has a similar situation :)

Comment: Should be using `.on` here. It's basically the same as delegate but switch the first and second parameters. Just a heads up!

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on the assumption that OP is using `<th>` elements. Still waiting for OP to post his markup.

You can prevent the event from bubbling/propagating up to the `<tr>` element if it is originating from a `<th>`, instead of a `<td>` element:

```
$('#listingTable').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var latitude = $(this).children('td').eq(3).text().trim();
    var longitude = $(this).children('td').eq(4).text().trim();
}).on('click', 'th', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

p/s: If you're using newer versions of jQuery, I would recommend migrating from `.delegate()` to `.on()`.

Here is a proof-of-concept JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/27Twe/

Answer (score 0):

try using tr in `<tbody>`

```
 <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>Cell1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Cell2</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


$("#myTable").delegate('tbody tr', 'click', function () {});
```